# censorword function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working on this function which basically takes two arguments. The first one is 
a number and the second is a list. I want to replace the first argument with 3 every single time I see it in my list.  My function works fine. Here it is:

```
censorword _ [] = [] 
censorword b (x:xs) 
        |  b == x = 3:censorword b xs 
        | otherwise = x:censorword b xs
```

My question is, how do I make it work for Strings. In other words, i would like to do something like this: censorword "ab" ["cdZ",ab"] = ["cdZ","hello"] . Here, I have replaced "ab" with hello.

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What doesn't work? Changing 3 to "hello" should be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to change the value being replaced (`3` in your original code).

```
censorword :: String -> [String] -> [String]
censorword _ [] = []  
censorword b (x:xs)
        |  b == x = "hello" : censorword b xs
        | otherwise = x : censorword b xs
```

This function can be generalized and simplified with `map`:

```
censorword' :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
censorword' a b = map (\x -> if x == a then b else x)

censorword' "ab" "he" ["ab", "he", "ab"] -- => ["he", "he", "he"]
```

Comment: The type annotation is optional.

Comment: Good point, I made it sound like it's part of the solution.. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Generalise.

```
censor :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
censor _           _      []       = []
censor replacement needle (x : xs)
    | needle == x                  = replacement : censor replacement needle xs
    | otherwise                    = x           : censor replacement needle xs
```

Then

```
censorword = censor 3
censorwordForStrings = censor "hello"
```

`censor` can be simplified:

```
censor :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
censor replacement needle = map censor' where
    censor' x | needle == x = replacement
              | otherwise   = x
```